# React JS How to reset a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How do I reset the values in a form in React JS onClick?

```
class AddFriendForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     firstname: '',
     lastname: '',
   }
 }

 render() {
    const { addFriend } = this.props

   const setFirstName = add => this.setState({ firstname: add.target.value })
   const setLastName = add => this.setState({ lastname: add.target.value })

return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <Label label="First Name" />
      <Field onChange={setFirstName} />

      <Label label="Last Name" />
      <Field onChange={setLastName} />

      <SecondaryButton
        name="Search"
        onClick={() => addFriend(this.state)}
      />

   <SecondaryButton
      name="Reset"
      onClick={() => ???}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
)
 }
}
```

When the user presses the Reset button, I want an onClick event that resets all the fields in the form to blank. Is there a single line of code to do this?

Comment: set the state of both values to an empty string, that will 'clear' it out

Comment: follow the pattern already there. (for example `setLastName `) and instead of setting the state to `add.target.value` set it to `""` as hjm said.

Comment: Don't call setState in render method !

Comment: where should it be called?

Answer (score 9):

First, create a function called resetForm

```
resetForm = () => {
   this.setState({
       ...this.state,
       firstname: '',
       lastname: ''
   })
}
```

Then trigger the function when reset button is clicked

```
onClick={this.resetForm}
```

Cheers mate

EDIT:

You have to assign the values to "Field" using value={this.state.firstname}

```
<Field value={this.state.firstname} onChange={...
```

Small tip: dont define your functions in your jsx code.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need ...this.state in setState unless you are trying to conform to immutable state and making a PureComponent, its just clutter if you don't do it everywhere.

Comment: This works but the form doesn't redraw, so the text typed still appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply like this.

Before the `render()` add below part. This is a function to reset the fields.

```
      reset = () => {
      this.setState({ firstname: ''})
      this.setState({ lastname: ''})
  }
```

And this where the function is called. (In Button `onPress`.)

```
<Button 
    title='reset'
    style={styles.button}
    onPress={this.reset}
    >
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:- use this one in functional component.

```
const handleReset = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

handleReset = () => {
setState(({
name: '',
email: '',
}))
}

Comment: Please use markdown for your answers that includes code blocks

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.